# Remove Phonegap as synonym of Cordova tag and make it independent again

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

When Adobe bought Phonegap back in 2011 and open sourced the current code as Apache Cordova they were synonyms, but Adobe kept the Phonegap brand and continued working on it, and now they are different.

Extract from [the Phonegap website](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-whate28099s-in-a-name/)

> What’s the difference between Apache Cordova and PhoneGap?
>
> PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache
>   Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is
>   the engine that powers Chrome or Safari. (Browser geeks, please allow
>   me the affordance of this analogy and I’ll buy you a beer later.)
>
> Over time, the PhoneGap distribution may contain additional tools that
>   tie into other Adobe services, which would not be appropriate for an
>   Apache project. For example, PhoneGap Build and Adobe Shadow together
>   make a whole lot of strategic sense. PhoneGap will always remain free,
>   open source software and will always be a free distribution of Apache
>   Cordova.

That time has come, now Phonegap contains additional tools and people using it usually follow a different workflow than people using Cordova (Phonegap desktop app, Phonegap developer app, etc), and some of them don't even know what Cordova is and get confused when you ask them about it on their questions.

When answering questions it's also good to know beforehand if they are using Phonegap or Cordova because the answer might be slightly or totally different and will save us time not having to comment on every question asking everytime they forgot to mention that they are using Phonegap and not Cordova.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've broken the synonym; you can now create a [phonegap] tag if you wish, and write a wiki that clearly distinguishes it from Cordova.