# How to remove an approved synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I have a been reading for a while to find out how I can remove an approved synonym to a tag. For a long time, it looked like I needed to "down vote" it. But apparently, you can only vote for synonyms that haven't been approved yet. Once the synonym is approved, I can't figure out how to remove the synonym. The synonym that I need to remove is the one that remaps `angular` to `angularjs`.

For a very long time, it made good sense to re-map all tags `angular` to `angularjs`. There is a synonym that does this. If you try to tag with `angular`, SO replaces the tag with `angularjs`. For a long time, this made good sense, as it was one and the same thing.

However, the Angular team at Google then released Angular 2.0, and announced that going forward, the Angular project would use proper Semver for releases. Subsequently they released Angular 3.0, and Angular 4.0. With the release# of the framework now increasing with normal Semver, it doesn't make sense to continue calling the framework `Angular 2` or `Angular 3`, and so on. The community and the Angular team has agreed that going forward, the term `AngularJS` refers to the `1.x` versions, and the term `Angular` refers to all versions that are `2.0` or higher.

This change created some difficulties for people building libraries for `Angular` (the `2.0` or higher version). An example is the Angular + Firebase library. Instead of calling their `1.x` compatible library `angularfire` and calling their `2.0 and higher` library `angularfire2`, they are scrambling to remove the `2` from `angularfire2`. They don't want to have to release a new npm package each time `Angular` bumps their major version.

So you see, the entire community around Angular is currently trying to adapt to the new naming, where `AngularJS` refers to the `1.x` branch, and where `Angular` refers to all releases `2.0` and higher. **It would be nice if Stack Overflow matched the new naming conventions.** If we could remove the synonym that remaps the tag `angular` to `angularjs`, that would be helpful. That way we could tag all `1.x` questions with the `angularjs` tag, and all questions for versions `2.0` and higher with the `angular` tag. I definitely don't want to see `angular2`, `angular3`, `angular4`, `angular5` tags, and so on. We need to have one tag for `2.0` and higher versions, and another for versions `1.x`. Since the community is referring to Angular this way, it would be nice if we could get the tags on Stack Overflow to match.

Any advice, please? We have several people in the Angular community who have access to all publicly available tools on Stack Overflow, and even they don't see any UI that would allow them to make these changes. We may need to help from the Stack Overflow team here.

The angular community has properly weighed in with their opinions on this [meta.stackoverflow.com post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2).

Comment: The Angular tags have been discussed a lot. For instance, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2 discusses the tags. Check out the "Linked" section on the sidebar of that question for other discussions on it, too.

Comment: Just to note a mod is required to remove synonyms once they're approved. Once the community has a firm plan in place as to what they want to do with Angular moving forward and also what to do with the legacy questions out there etc...

Comment: @JonClements based on the meta post Kendra linked to I would say the community already does have a firm plan in place. What seems to be lacking is someone who launches a mod into action. Can you elaborate (maybe in an answer) how the mod team wants to be involved in this?

Comment: @Kendra Have been discussed a lot, but what is the process for these discussions to actually result in decisions and/or actions? Who is in charge? Who decides? Jon Clements says a mod is required to remove synonyms "once they're approved"; who approves them, how? How does the "community" form a plan? As rene suggests, there is already a plan.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't have the answers, hence why I commented. I just pointed to a relevant and related discussion. I don't know why that prompted your questions to be fired at me, but if I had answers, I'd have posted them rather than just commented and left.

Comment: Good news is, this is done! http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info

Comment: I've been trying to remove phonegap synonym from cordova tag without success, I was told that if it had enough votes it would be removed. As this question has 28 upvotes and the synonym was removed, maybe you can help me upvoting my proposal. It has 20 upvotes already https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337612/remove-phonegap-as-synonym-of-cordova-tag-and-make-it-independent-again

Comment: @jcesarmobile, I am pretty sure that Stephen Fluin, from the Angular team, reached out to someone with Stackoverflow, and asked for help. Not sure how it happened. But glad that it did.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I'm from Cordova team and I know people from Phonegap team also want it to be a separate tag. Will try to reach somebody. Thanks

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230967/213575